# Does Bokeh allow nodes to be "any hashable object" like in Networkx?

Tags: python, bokeh, networkx

I have built a graph in Networkx and want to use Bokeh for visualization. I have the choice to start from scratch in Bokeh and use their Edge and Node Renderers, or use Bokeh's `from_networkx()` function. 
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#networkx-integration

An advantage for me in Networkx is

> In NetworkX, nodes can be any hashable object e.g., a text string, an image, an XML object, another Graph, a customized node object, etc.

And for my program each node is an instance of the Node class.
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#creating-a-graph

I found in Bokeh's documentation:

> The key feature of the GraphRenderer is that it maintains separate sub-GlyphRenderers for the graph nodes and the graph edges. This allows for customizing the nodes by modifying the GraphRenderer’s node_renderer property.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#edge-and-node-renderers

That led me to

> *attr* `node_renderer` 
>   *property type:* `Instance ( GlyphRenderer )`
>   Instance of a `GlyphRenderer` containing an `XYGlyph` that will be rendered as the graph nodes.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/renderers.html#bokeh.models.renderers.GraphRenderer.node_renderer

Which led me to finding out what it means to have the property type `Instance ( Glyph Renderer )`...

> `class Instance(instance_type, default=None, help=None)`
>        Accept values that are instances of `HasProps`.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh.core.properties.Instance

And then I tried to understand what `class HasProps` means and how each of the above things are related ...

> `class HasProps(**properties)`
>   Base class for all class types that have Bokeh properties.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/has_props.html#bokeh.core.has_props.HasProps

Can someone explain how these things work together and clear up what can or cannot be used as a `node_renderer` in Bokeh? 
I'm not understanding all the working parts.

Also, is there any advantage to integrating Networkx with Bokeh, or using Bokeh alone?

NOTE: I'm a beginner in Networkx and a fetus in Bokeh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off just FYI you have gone down a rabbit hole to towards things that are never relevant to typical Bokeh usage (most users will never hear of or use `HasProps` directly, e.g.)

For context:

```
node_renderer = Instance(GlyphRenderer)
```

means that `node_renderer` take values that are instances of type `GlyphRenderer`, and a `GlyphRenderer` is thing that knows how to draw glyphs (i.e. rects, circles, etc) on the screen. That's about as far down the codebase as I would expect anyone to ever need to go unless there were doing development on Bokeh itself, or creating custom extensions.

Bokeh plots draw glyphs by pulling data out of an associated `ColumnDataSource`. A CDS is kind of a cheap version of a Pandas DataFrame. It is (more or less) a dict that maps string column names to sequences (lists, arrays, series) of data. Usually the data are numbers, or in the case of categorical coordinates or color values, strings. Occasionally, for special glyphs like `multi_line` or `patches`, the columns are more like "lists of lists" of numbers.

When you add attribute data to a NetworkX graph, Bokeh tries to put the attribute data in one of these CDS columns. I am nearly certain that complicated attribute values like dicts, etc. will not work. Things like objects or classes certainly won't work, and the reason is that all this data has to ultimately be serialized and sent to a browser for a JavaScript library (BokehJS) to consume, and it would have no idea what to do with something like that.

TLDR; I would only expect scalar types such as numbers and strings to work, and also possibly lists of the same.